# How can method exist when not defined or implemented explicitly?

Tags: php

I thought maybe I was losing my mind, or just having a senior moment, when I about posted this question here.  But then I found the answer, which I've posted below, hopefully to help others who encounter this.

I'm using the FluentPDO library (https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo).  I was pushing the limits of its capabilities and the documentation is a bit lacking.  So I began looking at the code.  I could not find the implementation of the SelectQuery::select() function, even though the documentation mentioned it, I was able to use it, and it's used internally.

How can a function or method exist, without a declaration or implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in PHP's unusual "Overloading" of methods.

If a method is undefined, but the class contains a __call() method, __call() will be called instead, and passed the method name and its arguments.  This is what FluentPDO uses for some of its methods.

The PHP documentation is here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call